# vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline for text node

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, eslint-plugin-vue

I use "[eslint-plugin-vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-vue)"

I would like to use the rule "[vue/singleline-html-element-content-newline](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/singleline-html-element-content-newline.html)" in my projects but it works inconvenient for me
All the more because this rule is recommended:

> This rule is included in all of "plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended", "plugin:vue/strongly-recommended", "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended" and "plugin:vue/recommended".
> So, my problem is using text nodes without attributes:

```
<div attrs>
    <span attrs>Text<span>
</div>
```

that code is better for me than

```
<div attrs>
    <span attrs>
        Text
    <span>
</div>
```

because in the second case the text node is hanging in the air and it generates redundant code: `\n\t\tText\n\t`

- I know about the option "ignoreWhenNoAttributes" but it works only when no attributes.
- I can add all inline elements to the options list "ignores", but in this case, I have to add all my custom inline components. But eslint config creates for several projects.
- Yes, I can add custom components into the config for the particular project. But this becomes inconsistent.
- One more solution: wrap a text node into `<span>` element without attributes:

```
<div attrs>
    <my-component attrs>
        <span>Text<span>
    <span>
</div>
```

As I see it would be better to ignore the rule for text nodes.

Is there any other approach for text nodes?

Comment: Redundant code isn't a problem if template minification is in effect. Just make sure that the presence or absence of empty lines doesn't affect the layout.

Comment: Yes, redundant code, in general, is not a problem, I agree.
I found an option for "vue-template-compiler" `whitespace: 'condense'`
It transforms "\n\t\tText\n\t" to " Text  "